# How to create a temporary directory which will be automatically deleted whem JVM terminates?

Tags: java, file, file-io, directory, temporary-files

JDK 7 introduces an API called `Files.createTempDirectory`, but the directory created by the API is not automatically deleted when the JVM terminates.

And unfortunately `File.deleteOnExit` does not work with a non-empty directory.

Is there a way to create a directory which is automatically deleted when JVM terminates?

Comment: You might always replace the directory with a temporary Zip archive and store the resources/file contents inside that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

register custom [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)) with something like [deleteDirectory](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#deleteDirectory(java.io.File)) from Commons IO

Comment: i like the shutdown hook indeed

Answer (score 0):

The trick you can use is :

- While closing your application. get the list of all files in your tempDirectory using  list() method.
- For each file in list perform `delete()` operation.
- After that you can delete that directory.